# Should a HTTP Allow header contain "OPTIONS"?

Tags: rest, http, header, http-options-method

If a HTTP resource is not able to handle a request with the given HTTP method, it should send an `Allow` header to list the allowed HTTP methods. Another possibility to get a response with an `Allow` header is to send a request with the `OPTIONS` method.

I'm wondering whether the `Allow` header should contain the `OPTIONS` method itself.

Example:

```
Allow: GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

or

```
Allow: GET, PUT, DELETE
```

What is correct?

Comment: What makes you think that OPTIONS should not be included?

Comment: I'm wondering because a OPTIONS requests would include OPTIONS as allowed method too. This would be redundant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see why not. The `OPTIONS` request method is used to request information about the communication options available for the requested URI. Some clients use `OPTIONS` to determine communication requirements and the server's capabilities without having to retrieve or perform  an action on the requests resource.